# python - gc unreachable when reload()

Tags: python, python-2.7, garbage-collection, circular-reference

I have this code, save as so.py:

```
import gc
gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_STATS|gc.DEBUG_LEAK)

class GUI():
    #########################################
    def set_func(self):
        self.functions = {}
        self.functions[100] = self.userInput
    #########################################
    def userInput(self):
        a = 1
g = GUI()
g.set_func()
print gc.collect()
print gc.garbage
```

And this is the output:
[image]

I have two questions:

1. Why gc.collect() does not reports **unreachable** when first time import? Instead it reports **unreachable** only when reload().
2. Is there any quick way to fix this function mapping circular reference, i.e self.functions[100] = self.userInput ? Because my old project have a lot of this function mapping circular reference and i'm looking for a quick way/one line to change this codes. Currently what i do is "del g.functions" for all this functions at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The first time you import the module nothing is being collected because you have a reference to the `so` module and all other objects are referenced by it, so they are all alive and the garbage collector has nothing to collect.

   When you `reload(so)` what happens is that the module is reexecuted, overriding all previous references and thus now *the old values* don't have any reference anymore.

   You *do* have a reference cycle in:

   ```
    self.functions[100] = self.userInput
   ```

   since `self.userInput` is a bound method it has a reference to `self`. So now `self` has a reference to the `functions` dictionary which has a reference to the `userInput` *bound* method which has a reference to `self` and the `gc` will collect those objects.
2. It depends by what you are trying to do. From your code is not clear how you are using that `self.functions` dictionary and depending on that different options may be viable.

   The simplest way to break the cycle is to simply *not* create the `self.functions` attribute, but pass the dictionary around explicitly.

   If `self.functions` only references bound methods you could store the *name* of the methods instead of the method itself:

   ```
   self.functions[100] = self.userInput.__name__
   ```

   and then you can call the method doing:

   ```
   getattr(self, self.functions[100])()
   ```

   or you can do:

   ```
   from operator import methodcaller
   call_method = methodcaller(self.functions[100])
   call_method(self)   # calls self.userInput()
   ```

I don't really understand what do you mean by "Currently what i do is `del g.functions` for all this functions at the end." Which functions are you talking about?

Also, is this really a problem? Are you experience a real memory leak?

Note that the garbage collector reports the objects as *unreachable* not as *uncollectable*. This means that *the objects are freed even if they are part of a reference cycle*. So no memory leak should happen.

In fact adding `del g.functions` is *useless* because the objects are going to be freed anyway, so the one line fix is to simply remove all those `del` statements, since they don't do anything at all.

The fact that they are put into `gc.garbage` is because `gc.DEBUG_LEAK` implies the flag `GC.DEBUG_SAVEALL` which makes the collector put all *unreachable* objects into the `garbage` and not just the *uncollectable* ones.

Comment: You said unreachable is not the reason of memory leak, but why i have to fixed the unreachable reference cycle? And "del g.functions" is not useless, it does avoid the unreachable when reload().

Comment: @林果皞 Unreachable simply means that the garbage collector is going to deallocate them. It means that they are not reachable by any reference (outside their cycle). Memory leaks involve *uncollectable* objects, which wont be freed by the garbage collector. If you have a memory leak issue you should probably open a new question about that instead.  Note that if some of your objects implement a `__del__` method than they *may* become *uncollectable*. *In this case* using `del g.functions` may break the cycle allowing the garbage collector to collect them.

Answer (score 1):

1. The nature of `reload` is that the module is re-executed. The new definitions supersede the old ones, so the old values become unreachable. By contrast, on the first import, there are no superseded definitions, so naturally there is nothing to become unreachable.
2. One way is to pass the `functions` object as a parameter to `set_func`, and do not assign it as an instance attribute. This will break the cycle while still allowing you to pass the `functions` object to where it's needed.

Comment: 1. The unreachable only happen when i put this line " self.functions[100] = self.userInput". And i didn't get the reason.
2. I know instance attribute will cause this circular reference, but i'm looking for global/quick way to fix it while still keep it as instance attribute. Something like sys.exc_clear() solution.

Comment: If you're firm about wanting the instance to keep a pointer to the map, and also firm about wanting the map to contain a pointer to the instance, then you want a circular reference.

Comment: I get confused now, does "reference cycle" will cause any problem? Or it just a favor of style?

Comment: It causes memory leaks because the Python GC isn't guaranteed to find and free the cycle. If you undo the cycle before it becomes free (i.e. discard `functions` when you no longer need its `GUI` object), then the leak is fixed.

Comment: Hi, @Bakuriu answered me "This means that the objects are freed even if they are part of a reference cycle. So no memory leak should happen." But you just say "It cause memory leaks...". This two different conclusions make me really confused.

Comment: *Unreachable* objects **are** freed. *Uncollectable* objects are *not* freed (see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage)). In the example the OP is providing *thers is no memory leak*. The output simply means that the GC is going to free those objects (if they were reachable then they would have references alive). There would be a problem if the output was `gc: done, 8 unreachable, 8 uncollectable, xxxx elapsed`, but this is not the case *in the example*. If `GUI` had a `__del__` method there would be such kind of output and memory leak.